# How call View from inside the script tag in ASP .NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I work with ASP .NET MVC 5 . I write in View inside the script tag function.When I click the button view call this function.

I want check if my Function Returns "You pressed OK!" go to for example Login View , else if Returns "You pressed Cancel!" go to Index View . How can I do this ? I don't know how write HTML code for this condition .

I follow below code

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            if (confirm("Press a button") == true) {
                x = "You pressed Cancel";
                @Url.Action("Login", "Account");
            }
            else {
                x = "You pressed OK";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```html
                 <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" onclick="myFunction()"> </span> Exit</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your `@Url` like this

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")';
```